# Use xlsxwriter to color the content contained in a row, but not lock the color to that row number?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm using python with the pandas and xlsxwriter modules to format an excel file that is generated dynamically. I need certain rows to be colored yellow, depending on the content of one column. Here is my code ("data" is a pandas DataFrame where each row represents one person). Look for the # comment that points you to the relevant code I'm talking about:

```
def format_excel(data):

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('InviteList.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

    data.style.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, header=False, index=False)

    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

    # Styles
    yellow = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#fdf2d0', 'border': 1, 'border_color': '#C0C0C0'})

    # Hacky bypass of default header style that pandas imposes  
    for idx, val in enumerate(data.columns):
        worksheet.write(0, idx, val)

    # THIS IS THE RELEVANT CODE
    for row, employee in data.iterrows():
        if data.loc[row, 'rsvp'] == 'maybe':
            worksheet.conditional_format(row + 1, 0, row + 1, 15, {'type': 'no_errors', 'format': yellow})

    writer.save()
```

So basically the for loop checks to see if the row contains a 'maybe' in the 'rsvp' column and if so, uses the yellow formatting object on that row. This works fine, HOWEVER...

Let's say row 4 and 7 get colored yellow in my excel sheet. Now if I select a column and sort that column alphabetically or something like that, the yellow formatting STAYS in rows 4 and 7 instead of MOVING along with the content it needs to stay with.

So it looks like my implementation permanently locks rows 4 and 7 with yellow formatting, when what I need is for it to be more dynamic: it should stick with the rows containing a "maybe" in the 'rsvp' column, no matter where I move them.

**EDIT:**

Ok I fixed my issue by using `worksheet.set_row` instead of `worksheet.conditional_format`. But then I had an issue where the color would stick with the correct row but other formatting like font size and text wrap wouldn't, so I also had to include those in the definition of my yellow format object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need loop at the end. 
Let's say your "maybe" criteria is inside the column A and the data you want to be colored yellow is in the column B.
You only need to write the conditional format without loop like this :

```
worksheet.conditional_format('B1:B5', {'type': 'formula',
                                           'criteria': '=$A1="maybe"',
                                           'format': yellow})
```